# How to use include_directories correctly in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have two cmake files:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(as_math_engine)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(include/as_math_engine)
add_library(as_math_engine evaluable.h)
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

tests/CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories(libs)
add_executable(as_math_engine_tests src/main.cpp)
```

And I have this `include/as_math_engine/evaluable.h` file but, CMake tells me:

> Cannot find source file: evaluable.h

Why is it? And how can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you use Makefiles generator, you can do `make VERBOSE=1` to see exact command line used to compile `as_math_engine_tests`. This might help find the cause.

Comment: `include_directories` is meant to specify the include paths for the preprocessor/compiler, not to tell CMake where to find the files. You should have `add_library(as_math_engine include/as_math_engine/evaluable.h)`.

Answer (score 1):

`include_directories()` is best used to set include paths for multiple targets within a project, `target_include_directories()` is usually preferred.

There are probably better ways of setting up `as_math_engine` if it is going to be a header-only library.

You also need to use `add_library(as_math_engine include/as_math_engine/evaluable.h)` because the `add_library()` doesn't search for files.

[Header Only Library](http://mariobadr.com/creating-a-header-only-library-with-cmake.html) shows how to set this up and use it to avoid these kinds of problems.

Alternatively delete both `include_directories()` and use `target_include_directories(as_math_engine_tests PRIVATE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/as_math_engine" libs)` so that the `as_math_engine_tests` uses the proper include path.

Comment: Do you have some reference to support that first paragraph? AFAICT, I've got a few dozen projects that set up some common `include_directories` at the top level, and it's visible in all the `CMakeLists.txt` processed via `add_subdirectory`... and it's been working correctly for quite a few years. (Perhaps it doesn't propagate in the opposite direction?)

Comment: @DanMašek I wrote that because it didn't initially work for me but I've changed the answer.  The manual for `include_directories()` states: "They are also added to the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES target property for each target in the current CMakeLists file."  I put the `include_directories()` at the bottom of the file after the  `add_subdirectory()`.  None of the targets in the sub-directory had the include paths, but the targets in the main `CMakeLists.txt` did pick up the includes.  But putting `include_directories()` before `add_subdirectory()` propagates the includes into the sub-directory.